# remove iOS simulator plugins

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I want to stop receiving this error message when I run my iPhone app in the simulator:

> iOS Simulator 5.0 (v272) has not been tested with the plugin iPhone
>   Simulator Capture 1.1.2 (v1). As a precaution, it has not been loaded.
>   Please contact the plugin developer for further information.

I did install the `iPhone Simulator Capture` plugin a long time ago. Now I don't need or want this plugin.

I read the install script `create-plugins-directory.sh` from the [github project](https://github.com/davbeck/iPhone-Simulator-Capture/tree/master/Installer) for clues as to where the plugin might be. However the directories created by this script are empty. Perhaps the plugin is referenced in some plist used by the iOS Simulator. **How can I uninstall this plugin and stop receiving the warning message?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check both `/Library/Application Support/SIMBL/Plugins` for all users and `~/Library/Application Support/SIMBL/Plugins` for your active user?

**Update 1 (not true anymore, see Update 2)**

There is another potential method to solve your issue. Download the code from GitHub, and modify `Info.plist` key `SIMBLTargetApplications/MaxBundleVersion` value to the actual version of your simulator (272 per your question). Build the plugin yourself and put it in one of the path above (whichever your existing plugin is in).

**Update 2**

By checking the latest source code of the plugin, it seems that it doesn't have the upper limit of simulator version anymore. See change history on `Info.plist` in [a commit 9 month ago](https://github.com/davbeck/iPhone-Simulator-Capture/commit/cd78c97018526410d4161872a1f79497d6232ad7). So I think you can just download the latest source, build and replace the existing plugin if you wanna go on using it.

Comment: It was in `/Library/Application Support/SIMBL/Plugins`. Awesome, thanks!